# Is NAS operating system necessary?

Tags: nas, file-sharing

I currently have an old computer that has Windows 7 on it and I would like to use this machine to be used as a local file server at home. I am not looking to do anything other than using this computer to store music and videos which my other computers can access. My main requirement is fast transfer speed.

I have been doing a bit of research on how to go about this and found that to set up a home file server that using a operating system made for NAS might be a good idea.

My Questions: Is it really necessary that I should set up an new operating system for this? How is this option better than just a windows share method? Will it increase the transfer rate? Why does the task of serving files require a dedicated operating system?

BTW: hope this is the right board to post this question.

Thanks my fellow computer people.

Comment: perhaps many of the so-called NAS operating systems are linux based and use samba which simulates windows file sharing.

Answer (score 2):

No, if you had many users accessing files on a device, a NAS OS may be of benefit.  The main difference of a nas on commodity hardware is manageability.  Windows 7 is sufficient for the tasks you've outlined.

Comment: Windows 7 is more than capable.  The only real bottleneck would be disk speed.  If your current HDD is not capable of serving up video at a reasonable rate, SSDs have dropped in price so low, that there would no reason not to use one for storage.

Answer (score 1):

A NAS OS will typically require less resources.

The resulting advantage would therefore allow more memory to be used for disk cache since it wouldn't be used by the multiple unneeded components of Windows 7.

On the other hand, stripping down your Windows 7 installation to a bare minimum would also reduce its footprint and have the benefit of more convivial manageability, especially if you're more familiar with that OS.